# How to distinguish between testsuite and testcase on the report

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, allure

Using Selenium C# web driver with NUnit for automation. I am generating Allure report using command line and my report gets fantastically created but I need help on the following issue:
I have the following structure using Page object model (2 Test and 1 Page). Now when I see the report it shows at the top Test run (2 testsuites, 2 testcases) and each testcase is a testsuite. I want it to say 1 testsuites, 2 testcases. How do I do that?

```
namespace ApplicationName.TestCases
{
    [TestFixture]
    class VerifyCreateOrder
    {

        IWebDriver driver;
        [SetUp]
        public void Initialize()
        {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }

        [TestCase]
        public void doCreateOrder()
        {
            LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage();
            //some Assertion

         }
    }
}


namespace ApplicationName.TestCases
{
    [TestFixture]
    class SearchOrder
    {

        IWebDriver driver;
        [SetUp]
        public void Initialize()
        {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }

        [TestCase]
        public void doSearchOrder()
        {
            LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage();
            //some Assertion

         }
    }
}
```

The below is my LoginPage Page object:

```
namespace ApplicationName.Pages
{
    class LoginPage
    {

        public void doLogin(IWebDriver driver, String username, String password)
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.myxyzsite.com");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("xyz")).SendKeys(username);
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("xyz")).SendKeys(password); 
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("xyz")).Click(); 

        }
    }
}
```

I read about the NUnit suite attribute at http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=suite&r=2.5.5 and created a c# class with enumerator as described but how do i call it/wire it? What changes do I need to make for my test classes?

```
namespace NUnit.Tests
{
    public class MyTestSuite
    {
        [Suite]
        public static IEnumerable Suite
        {
            get
            {
                ArrayList suite = new ArrayList();
                suite.Add(new VerifyCreateOrder());
                suite.Add(new SearchOrder());
                return suite;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want it to say 1 testsuites, 2 testcases. How do I do that?

Without adding a Suite or similar, you could put both `Test` cases into the same `TestFixture`, since that's what the `testsuite` output is built from. You may be able to do that using a partial class, or you can simply conflate the two classes.  However, your `Suite` solution is a better choice.

> What changes do I need to make for my test classes?

Call NUnit with the option `/fixture:NUnit.Tests.MyTestSuite`.

---

Note that all of this has changed with [NUnit 3](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/wiki) and the `Suite` attribute is gone. I can't see any way to do what you want in NUnit 3 short of reorganizing your test cases.

If it's very important to merge tests into suites, you can use XSLT. The NUnit test result schema is quite straightforward and easy to manipulate using XSLT.